# C++ std deviation function?

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

Ok so, all the numbers being passed into this function as parameters, are returning correct values, I cant figure out why after i run this i get some ridiculous number as the standard deviation. i.e the number i get is (4.23947e10) or something along those lines, and the display function is skipping every other line.

```
  float stdDev(int arrayList [], int count, float average)
     {
         int deviation;
         int sum2 = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
         {
             sum2 += pow((arrayList[i] - average), 2);

         }

         deviation = sqrt(sum2 / (count - 1));
         return deviation;

     }
void displayList(int heightlist [], int weightlist[], int count)
//displays list of integers based on lists
{

        cout << "\tHeight(s)" << " " << "Weight(s)" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            cout << "\t[" << heightlist[i] << "]" << " " << "["<< weightlist[i] <<"]" << '\n';
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)` looks suspicious. Your array counts from zero `0` to `count - 1` so typically one would use: `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)` **note:** `<` not `<=`.

Comment: Note that `x*x` is generally much cheaper than `pow(x,2)`

Comment: Also your deviation is of type `int` it probably should be `float`

Comment: `double` is almost always a better choice that `float` unless you need to store so many of them that you need to trade accuracy for smaller variables

Answer (score 6):

I think you're going one too far:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
//                ^^
```

Probably meant `i < count`.

Also:

```
int deviation;
int sum2 = 0;
```

You mean `float deviation, sum2`?

Comment: what do you mean ? should i switch the deviation and sum2 variables to float?

Comment: @user3236101 Yes. You already promised to return a `float` from the declaration, so `deviation` definitely should be. And if you're losing precision in all your intermediate steps, then the final value will be very inaccurate.

Comment: The standard deviation issue has been fixed now, the issue i am having is with the output being displayed using the display method i have set for my arrays.

Comment: @user3236101 Same issue, loop counts one extra... you need to stop at `< count`.

Comment: Yea i changed the for loop that displays the arrays to < count and still the same error, it doesnt makes sense.

Comment: Oh, you have an i++ in your loop body, so you're double incrementing.

Comment: the simple things... i cant believe i overlooked it.